# When Reloading by Browser[F5] then,a state always will be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-firebase

`state.firebase.profile` always is `undefined` when I reload by browser.
Somehow, it goes well except for <kbd>F5</kbd> as far as I can see.

I check by using `console.log("TEST HERE"+ JSON.stringify(this.props.profile.name));`.

[image]

Where should I modify it...

```
class ReagtTagSample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      porco:""
      tags: [{ id: 'Yugoslavia', text: 'Yugoslavia' }, { id: 'India', text: 'India' }],
      suggestions: [
        { id: "England", text: "England" },
        { id: "Mexico", text: "Mexico" },
      ],
    };
  componentDidMount=()=>{
    console.log("TEST HERE"+ JSON.stringify(this.props.profile.name));
  }

  handleAddition(tag) {
    this.setState((state) => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
  }

  handleDrag(tag, currPos, newPos) {
    const tags = [...this.state.tags];
    const newTags = tags.slice();

    newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
    newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);
    this.setState({ tags: newTags });
  }
//ommit
  render() {
    const { auth, authError, profile } = this.props;
    return (
//ommit
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    profileUpdate: (user) => dispatch(Update(user)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Update);
```

```
Update= (user) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firestore = getFirestore();　
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
        const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
        firestore.collection('users').doc(authorId).set({
                name: user.userName,
                tags:user.tags,
            }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS' })
        }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'PROFILE_UPDATE_ERROR', err })
        })
    }
}
```

I would like to use `profile.name` as default input name...

```
          <div className="input-field">
            <label htmlFor="userName">DisplayName</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="userName"
              value={this.state.userName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

React state and props will be **reset** to their initial values when we **reload** the web app in browser using <kbd>F5</kbd> or refresh button (because the app restarts as fresh).

The console log in `componentDidMount` prints `undefined`:

```
componentDidMount = () => { 
  console.log("TEST HERE" + JSON.stringify(this.props.profile.name));

  // side node: you do not really need an arrow function here as it is a special 
  // lifecycle method. It will the `this` automatically binded with component instance
}
```

because, probably you are getting `this.props.profile` data through an API call. Hence, `this.props.profile` will receive its values asynchronously. You can see it on console log in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

---

#### Solution:

But if you want to set the **default** value of below `input` from `this.props.profile.name`, you can use either of these options:

**Option 1**: Using `key` and `defaultValue`. It will work because React components or elements re-render when their `key` is changed. And due to re-render it will read new `defaultValue`.

```
<input
  key={this.props.profile.name}
  defaultValue={this.props.profile.name}
  type="text"
  id="userName"
  value={this.state.userName}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

**Option 2**: Set the `userName` in state when data is available in props:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (this.props.profile.name !== prevProps.profile.name) {
    this.setState({
      userName: this.props.profile.name,
    })
  }
}
...
<input
  type="text"
  id="userName"
  value={this.state.userName}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```